# How common is the use of the term "primitive" to mean "antiderivative"?

Tags: analysis, terminology

I don't know if this should actually be asked on the English stackexchange.  It seemed like I would find better answers here.

I have all but finished an undergraduate degree in mathematics in the United States, but I have never once heard the term "primitive" to mean "antiderivative" until recently, when someone from Europe pointed it out to me.  According to him, it's a common term there.  So I was wondering if people could give me an idea of how common this term is, and where.  I know for sure that if someone says "primitive" to a math student in the US, that the student won't know what he is talking about. Does the reverse hold for "antiderivative" (or the also common "integral") elsewhere?

Comment: Spivak uses the term in his _Calculus_, which I think is quite popular in the US.

Comment: In Romania, from where I am from, the term primitive is used. I thought at first that the term primitive is not used in English, but as mentioned, there are books in English which use it.

Comment: I'm thinking that the standard term was "primitive", but at some point an American textbook writer invented the term "antiderivative", which has gradually become the most popular in calculus textbooks.

Comment: Re: last question. I think antiderivative is pretty self-explanatory (even if I find the word a bit ugly and unnecessarily complicated). Even if I had never heard it before, I would immediately have thought of an integral. (my native language is German and there Stammfunktion is the common term).

Comment: Here in Argentina (spanish language) the term "primitiva" is used, almost exclusively.

Comment: Here (Finland) the most common term would be the equivalent of '(indefinite) integral (function)', 'primitive' is a common alternative (followed by the Finnish equivalent of German Stammfunktion). We don't use anything resembling 'antiderivative', but I agree with Theo that such a word is self-explanatory.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.bymath.com/studyguide/ana/sec/ana8.htm), a primitive of say $3x^2$ is $x^3$ and the set of all primitives, $x^3+c$ where $c$ is any real number is the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 5):

Apostol's "Calculus" volume 1 uses "primitive" in that sense 41 times, whereas "antiderivitive" is only used 4 times. Two of those are in the main text, always as part of an "or antiderivative" after the term "primitive", and the other two are in the index.

Comment: Upvoted for cunning use of ctrl-F.

Answer (score 3):

In complex analysis the antiderivative is often refered to as the primitive.

Comment: Ah, that may be.  I've yet to take complex analysis (I will have it next semester).

Comment: I checked the book I will be using, "Complex Variables, Second Edition" by Ablowitz and Fokas, and "antiderivative" is in the index twice, but not "primitive".  Furthermore, I used Google Books to search for the word "primitive" within the book, and it found no results (but four results for "andiderivative").  So I think you are wrong about it being used universally in complex analysis.

Comment: i said often used.  not universally.   see ahlfors or conway

Comment: I've since taken two semesters of complex analysis and my professor never used the term (anti-derivatives aren't even that important in the field anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to [Richard Courant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Courant). In his 2 volume book *[Differential and Integral Calculus](http://books.google.com/books?id=eyC1nk9-YjkC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=richard%20courant%20differential%20and%20integral%20calculus%20primitive&source=bl&ots=v1jT5FD_04&sig=zd4-Is5vLnRjDJscLvPJfREdWsU&hl=en&ei=NacGTovtBYXo0QHJq4T9Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, he uses the term 'primitive' to mean antiderivative.

Comment: It's certainly a lot older than Courant.  See http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathword.html which traces "primitive" back to Lagrange in 1797.  For "anti-derivative" the first reference they have is 1903.

Answer (score 1):

I can just say that "the primitive function" (primitivní funkce) is the only official name of this object in Czech. Also, I think that the most standard English term is not "antiderivative" but rather "indefinite integral".

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative

Comment: "Integral" is used more often (ambiguously), but the rigorous usage always uses "antiderivative".  Rigorously, I think the difference might be that "indefinite integral" refers the the family of all possible antiderivatives (F(x) + C), whereas "antiderivative" refers to any one of those (F(x) is "an antiderivative" of f(x)).

Comment: Though I don't think it's exactly standard, I like the use (saw this in Apostol, I think?) of "indefinite integral" to specifically mean $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ for some f and a. Of course this turns out to be the antiderivative when f is continuous, but...

Answer (score 1):

In the Dutch language, the antiderivative is known as the "primitieve".

Comment: I know it as "primitieve".

Comment: While we're at what it's called in other languages: In Danish it's called "stamfunktion" as in "*f* stems from *F*"

Comment: In French it's only called "primitive" too, there's no equivalent for "antiderivative".

Comment: @Jonas, You are right, that is emberassing

Comment: @kahen: (Almost) the same in German: Stammfunktion