# Cauchy definite integral vs Riemann once again

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

The problem of showing the equivalence between the Cauchy (definite) integral defined below and the Riemann integral is an exercise with hint in C.R.Rosentrater, *Varieties of Integration*, 2015.

I am interested in one direction, precisely the one contained in exercise 32 of chapter 3. Its converse, easy to prove, is contained in exercise 38 chapter 2.

In what follows $\mathcal P_L$ indicates the partition $\mathcal P$ tagged by the left endpoints of its subintervals.
The symbol $S_R$ indicates a Riemann sum.
A Cauchy sum is a Riemann sum referred to a partition tagged by the left endpoints.

[image]

It is clear that $f$ is Cauchy integrable over $[a,b]\,$ only if,$\,$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $\delta>0$ so that, whenever $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$ are partitions of $[a,b]$ with $\|\mathcal P\|<\delta$ and $\|\mathcal Q\|<\delta$, one has $$|S_R(f,\mathcal P_L)-S_R(f,\mathcal Q_L)|<\varepsilon$$ Author suggests a proof by contraposition using a characterization of Riemann integrability, called there "height-width bounds theorem".

The statement to be proved is

**If $f$ is bounded and Cauchy integrable over $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$**

I restated what is written in exercise 32 because Cauchy integrability doesn't imply boundedness.
This problem appears here and there in the literature but, as far as I know, proofs are not at all elementary. Maybe Rosentrater's hint refers to an elementary one.
I don't know how to use the hint. I am waiting for a further hint at least.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably "Cauchy Integral" is a term from that book.  (Since it is not a standard term.)

Comment: @GEdgar It is not a standard term; anyway it is often used when one refers to the classical Cauchy definite integral defined using left endpoints as tags

Comment: Would it hurt to just give the definition of Cauchy integral?

Comment: @bof: Cauchy integral is Riemann integral with left end point of subintervals being chosen as tag points. The Riemann sums are thus of the form $\sum f(x_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})$.

Comment: I don't think such a question deserves a downvote. Rather it is one of those results which most textbooks have simply failed to provide.

Comment: The definition of Riemann may be paralleled with the definition of a converging sequence. The criterion of Cauchy may be paralleled with the definition of a Cauchy sequence. The definition of Darboux may be paralleled with this somewhat strange condition: we say that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ Darboux-converges if there is a pair of sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $a_n\leq x_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$, $a_n$ increases monotonically, $b_n$ decreases monotonically, and $b_n-a_n$ decreases monotonically to zero. The height widths bound here should be compared to Lebesgue's characterization.

Comment: Please don't make many inconsequential edits just to bump the question to the front page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is really interesting +1. Based on your earlier answers / comments I did read some proofs of equivalence of Cauchy and Riemann integrals but all of them are so crafty and complicated that I can't explain them to someone else (which implies that I don't understand them myself).

Hint a) appears simple, but I am not sure how to use it with b). The idea is that we can choose $s_k, t_k$ in interval $[x_{k-1},x_{k}]$ so that their values are close to the inf and sup. Ideally we need to involve some arbitrary number $\epsilon>0$ and we can choose $s_{k}, t_{k} $ such that $$f(s_{k}) - \inf_{[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f<\epsilon >\sup_{[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f-f(t_k)$$ In fact for a suitable $\epsilon$ it is possible choose the points such that $|f(s_k) - f(t_k) |>h$. The fact that $s_{k+1}=t_{k+1}=x_{k+1}$ automatically ensures that $$\Delta s_{k} =s_{k+1}-s_{k}\geq x_{k+1}-x_{k}=\Delta x_{k} $$ Essentially based on two adjacent subintervals of $\mathcal{P} $ we create a single subinterval of partitions $\mathcal{P}_{l},\mathcal {P}_{u} $. Thus their norms can not exceed $\delta$. Also this exercise can be carried out over at least half of the subintervals where the oscillation of $f$ is greater than $h$. The subintervals of partition $\mathcal{P} $ where the oscillation of $f$ is less than $h$ and if they are not adjacent to those selected half of the subintervals (with oscillation greater than $h$) are retained as it in both partitions $\mathcal{P}_{u}, \mathcal{P}_{l} $. Thus their contribution to the Cauchy sum get canceled when we subtract Cauchy sums over these two partitions. The difference $$|C(\mathcal{P}_{u}) - C(\mathcal{P}_{l}) |$$ depends on those points $s_k, t_k$. The difference $$|f(x_{k-1})(s_k-x_{k-1})-f(x_{k-1})(t_k-x_{k-1})+f(s_k) (s_{k+1}-s_k)-f(t_k)(t_{k+1}-t_k)|$$ needs to be analyzed properly to complete the proof. The above difference should come out to be not less than $h\Delta x_{k} $ and then the difference between Cauchy sums is at least $hl/2$. This is the contradiction needed.

Comment: Nice answer.  (+1)

Comment: There is no doubt Rosentrater's proof mimics [Gillespie's](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2007121.pdf) one. By the way your post makes the latter clearer. I think one has to use in some way an upper bound of $|f|$ ....

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: agree. I am still trying to complete this proof with more details, but not successful so far.

Comment: Can you understand what Gillespie says at the end of his paper ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: I will read it again before I can say anything.